Replicating the mongodb project aggregation in Typescript
My scenario: I am trying to build a typesafe wrapper around node-mongodb driver. I am having a hard time figuring out the return type for project aggregation stage.
Have a look at the TS Playground here
class BaseAggregate<Coll> {
  private pipeline: Pipeline<Coll>[] = [];
  constructor(initialPipeline?: typeof this.pipeline) {
    if (initialPipeline) {
      this.pipeline = initialPipeline;
    }
  }

  match(stageInput: DeepPartial<Coll>) {
    return new BaseAggregate<Coll>([...this.pipeline, { $match: stageInput }]);
  }

  projectActual(stageInput: Record<keyof Coll, 0 | 1>) {
    return new BaseAggregate<T>>([
      //  what goes here ----^ instead of T?
      //   ...this.pipeline,
      //   { $project: stageInput },
    ]);
  }
}


interface Test {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const agg = new BaseAggregate<Test>()
  .match({ name: "john" })
  .match({ email: "sir john" })
  .match({ email: "sir" })
  .projectActual({ email: 0, name: 1 })

I need help declaring the return type of the projectActual() function such that the return type for above example will be
interface {
name: string;
}

Thank you for your time 

"I was expecting error at that [k: number]: boolean line" Why? Unclear what you're trying to achieve. StringMap<string | number | boolean>; evaluates to {}, and your UserSettings correctly extends {}.

Record<StringKeys<T>, T> doesn't really make sense as StringKeys appears to expect an object for use with keyof

@Bergi yes, setting up to make use of keyof.

@RobbyCornelissen I am trying to put together a query builder for mongodb. I am trying to implement the project stage of mongodb aggregation pipeline.
I will add more info in the question.

There's a significant amount of code in your playground link that isn't here as plaintext; please either add it here or remove it from the link... a [mre] has to be plaintext here in the question. Is that stuff important? The ChangeToZeroOrOne is quite complicated for what's effectively Record<keyof T, 0 | 1> (T[K] extends any is always true). And DeepPartial doesn't need to check of object (that naturally happens with homomorphic mapped types). I'm trying to figure out if the stuff in that link is important or a distraction. Please [edit] to clarify.

(see prev comment) • I also don't see how the new stuff has anything to do with "string keys" as opposed to numeric keys. How does that relate? • If I take your plaintext use case code at face value I'd say you can use a type mapping as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I have cleaned up the playground. The playground link you provided is what i am looking for. I tried implementing your solution and ts is no longer complaining but i have lost type inference when i chain methods. Please have a look at the playground.

Note: it would still be very helpful if you [edit] to bring the relevant code from the playground to here as plaintext in the question. I'm happy to look at the playground but it needs to be here on Stack Overflow directly also. I don't see anything here about method chaining (or about methods at all). It feels like maybe you're asking a followup question about some problem you ran into after solving this one, but I can't be sure without a [mre] in the question itself. And when I look at the playground I don't know where the inference issue is.

@jcalz i have changed the question here. The example you provide is what i am looking for but when i applied it to the ProjectActual function TS no longer complains but type inference is gone, try chaining one more method to below line.
const agg = new BaseAggregate<Test>()
  .match({ name: "john" })
  .match({ email: "sir john" })
  .match({ email: "sir" })
  .projectActual({ email: 0, name: 1 })

I have used typescript in the past but never at this level and i am still trying to wrap my head around this. Please let me know if you know any better approach to this.

Does this version meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining. Either way, important: please [edit] to take my unattributed suggested code out of your question (that's part of an answer, not your question), and instead put in an example of your code with methods, etc., and explain what your use cases are. As plaintext code and verbal descriptions in the text of the question itself. (Not just as a comment. Comments can and do get deleted without a trace.)

Yes @jcalz thats it . TYSM

Please don’t put my suggestions in your question.  I’m going to write an answer when I get a chance. The solution belongs in an answer, not in the question. I will probably [edit] your question if you don’t, but I think we would both prefer it if you did it.

@jcalz please go a head and edit as per your wish

I'll do so when I get a chance, might be tomorrow (I'm traveling today)

I think you want projectActual() to have the following generic call signature:
declare projectActual<R extends Record<keyof T, 0 | 1>>(
  stageInput: R
): BaseAggregate<{ [K in keyof T as R[K] extends 1 ? K : never]: T[K]; }>

So stageInput is of  generic type R constrained to Record<keyof T, 0 | 1>, meaning that stageInput has to have every key that T has, but the values should be either 0 or 1.
Then the type argument for the BaseAggregate output type is { [K in keyof T as R[K] extends 1 ? K : never]: T[K] }, a key-remapped mapped type that for each key K, checks if R[K] is 1. If so, then the property is output as-is, otherwise it is suppressed (if you remap a key to never, it is omitted from the resulting type). This is basically a Pick<T, Keys> where Keys is the set of keys of R which have a value type of 1.

Let's test it out:
 interface Test {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const agg = new BaseAggregate<Test>()
  .match({ name: "john" })
  .match({ email: "sir john" })
  .match({ email: "sir" })
  .projectActual({ email: 0, name: 1 })

/* const agg: BaseAggregate<{
    name: string;
}> */

Looks good. agg is of type BaseAggregate<{name: string}>; the email property has been suppressed effectively.
Playground link to code
